# Cannot convert from string to System.Windows.Forms.Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set an error message in the variable `txtURL` but I get the error message `Cannot convert from string to System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

The error is on this line 
`frmweb.ErrorMelding.SetError(frmweb.URL, "Je hebt geen url ingegeven");`

Here is the code I am using

`Webbrowser_Functions.cs`

```
public void Navigeren(frmWeb frmweb)
{
    // Als URL leeg is error melding weergeven
    if (frmweb.pu_txtURL == "")
    {
        frmweb.ErrorMelding.SetError(frmweb.URL, "Je hebt geen url ingegeven");
    }
}
```

`frmWeb.cs`

```
public string pu_txtURL;

public string URL
{
    get { return txtURL.Text; }
    set { txtURL.Text = value; }
}

Logical_Layer.Webbrowser_Functions ww = new Logical_Layer.Webbrowser_Functions();

public void btnNavigeer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtURL.Text = pu_txtURL;
    ww.Navigeren(this);
}
```

Comment: The error is rather clear. You tried to pass a string to [a method that expects a control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you mean to write `SetError(frmweb.txtUrl,...)` perhaps?

Comment: What is _ErrorMelding_ what is the code of _SetError_ ?

Comment: @Steve the Windows Forms ErrorProvider

Comment: Crystal ball says that you use the ErrorProvider component to display mistakes.  Its first argument requires a Control, not a string.  So you'd have to pass txtURL.  Which right now is a private variable of the frmWeb class so you can't.  The problem is caused by Webbrowser_Functions, it tries to do too much with variables it does not have access to.  Consider adding a public method to frmWeb to report the error.  Or simply making Navigeren() a method of that form class.

Answer (score 2):

[`SetError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the `Control` you want to set the error on as first argument, not a string.

So you probably wanted something like:

```
frmweb.ErrorMelding.SetError(frmweb.txtURL, "Je hebt geen url ingegeven");
```

But actually it has a smell that the `Control`s of your `frmweb` are accessible from outside. It seems better to make `Navigeren` an instance method of your `Form`.